# What's the most pandiastic way to join 2 instances of pd.Index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas index instances that come from different functions / a bit of a complicated mask to get to those.
I would now like to combine those, i.e., define a 'combined index' that holds all labels contained in either of the two.
My friend pd.concat() cannot be applied to 2 index instances.
What's the best way to combine them?
Here is 'kind of' what I would like to do, but which fails

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['foo', 'bar'])
setA = df[df['foo'] == 1].index
setB = df[df['bar'] == 4].index
pd.concat([setA, setB])
```

What I would like to get is the equivalent of the below, however obviously without combining the masking into a single function: Rather keep retrieving the 2 index instances `setA` and `setB` separately, as I have them already, and combine the output, not their definition.

```
df[(df['foo'] == 1) | (df['bar'] == 4)].index
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Is the only way really to get both, drop duplicates, and re-obtain the index? That looks super cumbersome...

```
pd.concat([df.loc[setA], df.loc[setB]]).index.drop_duplicates()
```

Surely there must be a better way than just brute-force getting an unnecessary amount of data, dropping what is unnecessary, and then getting the index (which I had in the first place anyway)

Comment: `df.index[(df['foo'] == 1) | (df['bar'] == 4)]` is same with (and a bit better than) your second approach. Both are slightly different than the `concat` approach (which may contain duplicate indexes).

Comment: Yeah, but that's exactly *not* what I am looking for! I don't want to combine all possible conditions into a single statement and then get the index. I want to combine 2 indices that I already have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html)

```
setA.union(setB)
```

---

```
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```